# Parsing json with jquery to build a dynamically populated select

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have to build a dinamically populated select but i'm pretty noob to this and i've encountered some difficoulties with json parsing...

my code is

```
cb="";
$('#datepicker').blur(function() {
    cb='<option value="0"></option>';
    if ($('#datepicker').val() != "") {
        $.getJSON("json.php?t=cb&id=" + $("#datepicker").val(), function(data){

            *some magic*

            *for each pair of element in json*
                 cb+='<option value="'+data.id+'">'+data.description+'<option/>';

        });
    }
    $('#select').html(cb);
});
```

sadly without magic tricks :(

the json i have to parse is like

```
[{"id":5423,"description":"sometext1"},
{"id":4132,"description":"sometext2"}
{"id":5534,"description":"sometext3"}
...
]
```

but i don't know how to do it...
can you help me?

sorry for my bad English :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify your code like this:

```
$.getJSON("json.php?t=cb&id=" + $("#datepicker").val(), function(jsonData){
     cb = '';
     $.each(jsonData, function(i,data){
         cb+='<option value="'+data.id+'">'+data.description+'</option>';
     });
     $("#select").append(cb);
});
```

Comment: Just a small change in the code change option closing tag. Thanks for the code.